# Script to read file per line and extract keys and values into variables?

Tags: python, regex, sed

I have a file (filename.txt) that has multiple key=value entries.
I want to write a python script that will do following:

1. Read each line of a file
2. For each line, extract key into a variable named 'key' and value into a variable named 'value'
3. Print both the variables 'key' & 'value' for line1 and then proceed to line2

sample file-

```
firstname=john
lastname=gates
age=12
```

expected output-

```
firstname john
lastname gates
age 12
```

I have used below regex and sed command which works fine. Facing trouble writing the for loop and capturing values in 2 variables for each line

```
cat filename.txt | sed 's/.*=//'
cat filename.txt | sed 's/=.*//'
```

Comment: Wait, are you aware that there are python tools to do that job, namely `split`?

Comment: You're just changing the first and only `=` to a space, so go for `sed 's/=/ /' filename.txt`, even though I have no clue what the heck you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read in the file and save the values, probably, as a dictionary:

```
kvps = {}
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    kvps = dict(line.strip().split('=') for line in f)
```

Now, to print the keys and values, just use

```
for k,v in kvps.items():
    print(f"{k} {v}")

# firstname john
# lastname gates
# age 12
```

If you just want to print the keys and values, you  may use

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(" ".join(line.strip().split('=')))
```